# Negation of Formal Logic

Tags: logic, negation

What domain is `U` and what is `P(x)` in order for this statement to be false?

```
∀x∈U, P(x) ⇒ ∃x∈U, P(x)
```

I don't think this is possible but I am hoping someone can figure out how to make this statement false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine that if U is the empty set, that statement is false; there does not exist any element in U, not least one that satisfies P(x). The antecedent is a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), but is nevertheless still true.

Comment: But if the statement is vacuously true, then it is still true, not false

Comment: @Brian: The *antecedent* is a vacuous truth, and is thus true, but the *consequent* is false. Because there is a case where the antecedent is true and the consequent is false, that means that the implication is false.

Comment: Hmm that's true because the antecedent is only true by default vacuously and not by proof. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah an empty set all elements will satisfy all properties but not a single element will. For people in the future for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set#Properties